# Goland automatic formatting

Tags: go, goland

Is it possible to tweak how Goland automatically formats, adds, and removes imports?  It keeps removing an import that my program needs to function so I need to keep manually re-adding it after every push, and it's driving me nuts.

Also, is it possible to set Goland so that it automatically formats (as in `go fmt`) on save?

Answer (score 5):

You should go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Actions on Save
and turn off "Reformat code" and "Optimize imports"

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to tweak how Goland automatically formats, adds, and removes imports?

I suspect that [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/2021.1/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#b174bdc0) (Git | Commit -> Settings -> Optimize imports ) is the option you are looking for (note that there are a lot of other relevant settings on the referenced page).

Note that unused imports result in a compilation error (e.g. `imported and not used: "net/http"`) so this may be something you want to resolve before checking code in.

> Also, is it possible to set Goland so that it automatically formats (as in go fmt) on save?

You can run `go fmt` on save but there are a number of factors to consider which are covered in [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2021/01/12/running-go-fmt-on-save/) (main consideration is that GoLand has its own formatter). In summary the current state (from the link) is:

> Currently, GoLand offers three ways to interact with ‘go fmt’: dedicated actions, before commit tools, and file watchers.
>
> Under the Tools | Go Tools menu, you can find two actions related to code formatting: Go Fmt File and Go Fmt Project. Each has a shortcut assigned to it: Alt + Shift + Control + F (Alt + Shift + Cmd + F on macOS) and Alt + Shift + Control + P (Alt + Shift + Cmd + P), respectively. The sole purpose of these actions is to run ‘go fmt’, providing it with either file paths or a path to the project directory, and they only work when you invoke them manually.
>
> There are several hooks that can be run before a commit. They can be configured via Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | Commit | Before Commit. There you can find Go fmt, which is enabled by default.
>
> The third way is to configure a file watcher. Under Settings (Preferences), you can find Tools | File Watchers. It’s easy to add a new watcher by using the predefined ‘go fmt’ template. Whenever a Go file is changed, the command is executed on it. The key word in this case is “whenever,” as users don’t have full control over the precise moment a file gets modified. I’ll describe this problem in more detail in the next session.